# Blazor server: how to free memory when changing page

Tags: c#, memory-management, blazor-server-side

I am building a **Blazor Server app** and I used the basic template (WeatherForecast).

I just changed the WeatherForecastService in order to return 50000 WeatherForecasts instead of the detfault value.

When I navigate from **Home** to **Fetch data**, then go back to **Home** I can see that the memory stored from Fetch data is still here.

The more I am doing the page change between Home and Fetch data the more memory the application is taking.

I am using **.NET 8.0**, all the default setup.

I looked online, found some topics about it but nothing that really helped me at the end.

I tried to do it using **GC.Collect**, clearing the forecast list and set to null during Dispose call

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    if (forecasts != null)
    {
        forecasts.Clear();
        forecasts = null;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you storing all 50k in memory in the backend? You should into using `yield return` to serve up that much data lazily, and grabbing only as much as you need with LINQ...You ought to add some code snippets as to how that data is stored and it would be simpler to advise on this. A given web page does not need to serve 50k forecasts, so in Razor you can `.Take()` as many as you intend to display

Comment: I do not think the memory-leaks tag is correct here

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Well you might be correct leak is maybe too strong for what it is.  The point I wanted to demonstrate is that memory is not freed when changing page.
I would have expect my forecast object instances to be removed at some point when changing page. Basically if I have some objects used in a component/page I was expecting them to be removed when not used anymore.

Comment: see one thing about dotnet's Garbage Collector, it highly prefers to do its own thing with limited intervention. Your attempts to [induce collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/induced) can accidentally reduce performance. This is mainly why I recommend looking into a lazy collection. It is not a good practice to have a collection that huge in memory. I understand this is a sample/demo app, but this is something that would avoid tinkering with the GC unecessarily